# Append new page to document without page break using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, page-break

I am combining the contents of multiple html files to produce a single PDF using wkhtmltopdf e.g.

```
wkhtmltopdf page1.html page2.html page3.html output.pdf
```

The generated PDF starts a new page after each of the html pages that I add.  I want to be able to control this e.g. in the example above I might want a page break between page1 and page2, but not between page2 and page3.  So the contents of page3 would be appended to page2.  I know that I could achieve this by concatenating the html for pages 2 and 3 into a single html file before sending them to wkhtml2pdf.  However I do not want to do this as I want to be able to pass page specific options for each page - particularly the option to exclude a particular page from the TOC and/or outline.  So I might want to include the contents of page2 in the TOC/outline but exclude the contents of page3 from the TOC/outline.

How can I maintain the ability to pass options for each page but control which pages have breaks after/before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying the Essential Objects PDF components to enable me to achieve what I wanted.  The work very well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `wkhtmltopdf` has the ability to do what you're asking. You can use the [**PDFtk toolkit**](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to get what you want. Take a look at [the examples](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/), and the [documentation for `cat` argument](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-cat).